# can't convert Symbol into Integer when trying to access hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

So I'm trying to access the test variable in this hash:

```
a = {:info=>#<test: "Testvar">}
```

I tried it with a[:info]['test'] or a[:info].test but I always get "can't convert Symbol into Integer" as error. What am I doing wrong? I guess it's pretty basic stuff but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `#<test: "Testvar">` is just the string representation of an object, which would be accessible at `a[:info]`. You could try printing `a[:info].inspect` or `a[:info].to_yaml` to try to figure out what that object is.

Comment: Inspect really helped finding the error so I'll accept this answer :)